# Selenium : Selecting elements with similar properties using sequence

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need some help with the selenium script i'm writing using c#.

I'm trying to click an element by the using "class" property but the issue is, there is another similar element that shares the exact same property and this element comes first hence my click,is hitting the first element instead

Also "Class" is the only attribute available for this element.

The element that i'm looking to click is "cam-taxpicker-button" under the "progressTerm" class

```
<div id = "LeftDivision" class = "LeftFrame">
 <div>
  <div class="cam-taxpicker">
    <div class="cam-taxpicker-button"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="progressTerm">
  <div class="cam-taxpicker">
   <div class="cam-taxpicker-button"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way keep these elements in a list and iterate to the second element and only then perform the action? Is this the best way for this?

Or is there any other way to perform this action?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML

Comment: Added more outerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find all elements with the same property you can make use of the `driver.FindElements();` method of selenium WebDriver.

So in your case, in order to find all elements with class name 'cam-taxpicker-button' you can do something like this :

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("cam-taxpicker-button"));
```

Now it will give you a collection of elements which matches the given ClassName and if there are only two elements you can click on the second element by doing : 
    elements[1].Click();

You can also do `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='cam-taxpicker-button'][2]")).Click();` but in this case it will always find only second element in the whole DOM with given class name.

Comment: Selecting the elements in the ReadOnlyCollections solved the issue. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='cam-taxpicker-button'][2]")).Click()
```

Here [2] in xpath represents the second element you want to click.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `XPATH` if there is more than one element with same class name exists it will identify the last one.If there is only one element present it will identify as well.

```
(//div[@class='cam-taxpicker-button'])[last()]
```

Induce `WebDriverWait` And wait for the `ElementToBeClickable`() and use the above xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("(//div[@class='cam-taxpicker-button'])[last()]"))).Click();
```

Let me know how it goes.